# SQL like operator, can I obtain results based on multiple words?

Tags: sql, sql-like

I'm using SQL Like operator in asp for my project, and I want to obtain all the results that have the words that I inserted in the search field.

So, if I search "fish restaurant", I'd like to obtain all the restaurants that have both "fish" and "restaurant" in the fields I'm searching.

So far, my code is as follow:

```
sql = "SELECT dbo.tbl_activity where (name like '%"&MySearchCriteria&"%' OR  description like '%"&MySearchCriteria&"%' OR  metadescription like '%"&MySearchCriteria&"%' OR  products like '%"&MySearchCriteria&"%' OR brand like '%"&MySearchCriteria&"%') "&QueryAdd&" Order By Nome"
```

is it a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is fine.

However you can make the query a bit more pleasant to read like this:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    tbl_activity
WHERE   CONCAT_WS(' ', name, description, ...) LIKE '%fish%'
AND     CONCAT_WS(' ', name, description, ...) LIKE '%restaurant%'
AND     ...
```

...and so on for each word in your search field